# When using the Serverless framework, my environment variable is being parsed as a number

Tags: types, environment-variables, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have an application which uses an environment variable. The environment variable itself is a bunch of numbers with a dot in the middle, e.g. `36478236853794287.234798237543893`, yet it should be interpreted as a string. I want to deploy this application on AWS Lambda using the Serverless framework.

I have set the environment variable in a separate file (`secrets.yml`), which is .gitignored:

```
dev:
  MY_ENV_VAR: 36478236853794287.234798237543893
```

I then included it in `serverless.yml` like this:

```
provider:
  environment: ${self:custom.secrets}

custom:
  stage: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
  secrets: ${file(secrets.yml):${self:custom.stage}}
```

However, when I print out `MY_ENV_VAR` in my application, the log shows it as a scientifically formatted number, like `'3.6478236853794287E14'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value as defined in the YAML file is being interpreted as a number. Enclose it in single quotes to make it explicit that it's a string:

```
dev:
  MY_ENV_VAR: '36478236853794287.234798237543893'
```